# Удаление и Изменение данных без перезагрузки страницы в таблице

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

У меня есть в БД дочерная таблица c определенными данными. Я её вывожу с помощью ajax. Вот js код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Show_Performance_ST').bind("click", function () {
    $("#div_Table_Prefromance_ST").remove();
    $.ajax({
      url: "poseschenie_zanyatiy.actions.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        "ajax": "3",
        "student": $("#student").val()

      },
      success: function (output_P) {

        $("div.container_P").append($(output_P));

      }
    });
  });
});
```

Вот php код:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 3){
  $student=$_POST['student'];

  $tbl_Performance1="<div class='row' id='div_Table_Prefromance_ST'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
              <table name='table_P' class='pefrom_each_ST'>
              <tr class='table_tbl_Performance'>
                <td>Семестр</td> 
                <td>Рік навчання</td>
                <td>Дисципліна</td>
                <td>Вид контролю знань</td>
                <td>Кількість балів</td>
                <td>За національною шкалою</td>
                <td>За шкалою ECTS</td>
                <td>Викладач</td>
                <td>Дата складання дисципліни</td>
                <td>Номер відомості</td>
                <td>Тип відомості</td>
              </tr>";

  if ($result= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usp 
    inner join tipv on tipv.TIPV1=usp.USP9
    inner join uchgod on usp.USP3=uchgod.uchgod1
    inner join predm on usp.USP4=predm.predm1
    inner join vidkont on usp.USP5=vidkont.id_vida_kontrolya
    inner join prep on usp.USP8=prep.PREP1
    WHERE  USP1=".$student)) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $semestr=$row['USP2'];
      $academYear=$row['uchgod2'];
      $subj=$row['predm2u'];
      $kontSubj=$row['ua_nazva_kontrolya'];
      $mark_100 = $row['USP6_100'];
      $mark_scale = $row['USP6'];
      $mark_ECTS = $row['USP6ECTS'];
      $lect_surName=$row['PREP2U'];
      $lect_Name=$row['PREP3U'];
      $lect_patronymic=$row['PREP4U'];
      $date = $row['USP7'];
      $number_Vedom= $row['USP10'];
      $type_Vedom= $row['TIPV2'];

        $tbl_Performance1 .= "  <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$semestr' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$academYear' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text'  value='$subj' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text'  value='$kontSubj' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$mark_100'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$mark_scale' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$mark_ECTS' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$lect_surName ' /></td>
                    <td><input type='date' value='$date' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$number_Vedom' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='$type_Vedom' /></td>
                    <td><a href='#' class='del_button'> X </a></td>
                  </tr>";
    }
  }
  $res_table1.="</table></div></div>";
  echo  $tbl_Performance1;

}
```

Получается в итоге вот такое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо сделать возможность удаления отдельно каждой строчки и изменения без перезагрузки страницы. Из-за того что это дочерная таблица, у меня не получается это сделать, так как нельзя просто по id взять и всё сделать. Изменения нужно сделать так, что бы по клику на ячейку она становилась активной и можно было там уже изменять и потом либо по кнопке, либо по клику по области оно сохранялось. Помогите с советом или примером.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать например вот так:

```
<tr data-item="1">...</tr>
```

Где 1 - это например вывод ID (номер строки) из вашей БД.
Допилим JS:

```
function del_tr(d) {
    var gettrid = d.getAttribute('data-item');           
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: { del: gettrid },
        success: function(response){
            var messageResp = new Array('Успешно удалено', 'Ошибка базы данных');
            var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
            if(response == 0) {
                //обновляем js вывод вашей таблицы
            }
            $("#del-id").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800); // можно сделать вывод сообщения о результате кода в div с id #del-id. (<div id="del-id"></div>
        }
    });
}
```

И отдельно файлик delete.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['del'] != '') {  
    $del = $_POST['del'];
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usp WHERE id='".$del."'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM usp WHERE id='".$del."'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
            echo 0; //Успешно удалено
        }
    } else {
        echo 1; //Ошибка, ниче нету
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    exit;
} ?>
```

Кнопка X в строке, например так:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="del_tr(this);" data-item="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

Код взял из своей работы, надеюсь подключение к БД типо $link и почему его нет выше никого не смутит. Не сложно подключить думаю)

Comment: data-comment-id="'.$id.'", а  это что за айди?

Comment: это ID строки из БД. Для каждого <tr> устанавливайте перманентный ID из БД.

Comment: Исправил пост, не верно указал аттрибут в примере.

Comment: то есть в БД надо добавить еще 1 столбец с айди( это будет по типу айди строчки) и потом по этому айди удалять ? Я думал об этом, но  не повлияет это на что-то или по-сути нечего не поменяется, просто будет удобно брать строчки для работы с ними ?

Comment: для удобства часто делают AUTO_INCREMENT. Установите этот параметр на новый столбец ID в своей БД. Это даже упростит Вам работу с БД, т.к. эта функция позволяет изменять или удалять строки из БД без SQL запроса,а через обычный интерфейс phpmyadmin.

Comment: Советую в каждой таблице Mysql использовать этот параметр для удобства дальнейшего использования :)

Comment: Да, я так и сделал. а столбец id , я поставил просто key и AUTO_INCREMENT. Правильно же ? он не должен же быть праймери или юник ?